# Large bitmap under a ListView/ScrollViews slows the scrolling

Tags: java, android, listview, bitmap, scrollview

I have the following layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/layout_1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/1dot6_mb_bitmap">
<include layout="@layout/top_bar"/>
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/layout_3"      
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout> 
<include layout="@layout/bottom_bar"/>
```

When I set the large bitmap as background for the layout_1 container, the ListView scrolls very slowly. If i remove the image from the background, the ListView scrolls perfectly. I tried also with a ScrollView and it's the same behavior.
I cannot use a repeating image or a 9.png because the large image is in fact a  landscape photo.
Do you any idea how can i solve this issue ? Or what is the reason the ListView/ScrollView behaves so slowly in this case?

Thank you

Comment: Is the whole background redrawn when scrolling ?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption the image is larger than the space it occupies, you can load it into member, using  the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class to resize the image before inserting it into the layout.

Comment: Ollie C> I already tried this and there is no much difference... and the image has the same resolution as the tablet screen.

Comment: In that case I think you're hitting the limits of the platform. Android doesn't handle graphics as well as iOS for example, so scrolling can by quite lumpy. I am hopeful the Android devs will improve things with Ice Cream Sandwich later in the year. In the meantime the only thing I can suggest is to consider RenderScript